# UIButton Bluetooth Toggle

Tags: swift

I have setup my app to automatically connect to bluetooth when the app is launched, but I wanted a force reconnect button to be used if connection is dropped. My button uses the same code as the initial search and connect that is used under viewDidLoad().

YES I know about the auto reconnect feature and it is enabled, but this is how I want it.

```
@IBAction func BTButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
        bluejay.start() //Call Bluejay

        bluejay.scan( //Begin and format BLE scanning
            duration: 10, serviceIdentifiers: [self.serviceID],
            discovery: { [weak self] (discovery, discoveries) -> ScanAction in
                guard let weakSelf = self else {
                    return .stop
                }

                if (discovery.peripheralIdentifier.name == self!.deviceName) {
                    self!.pI = discovery.peripheralIdentifier
                    return .stop
                }

                weakSelf.discoveries = discoveries
                return .continue
            },
            stopped: { (discoveries, error) in

                //Once the correct device is found, connect\\
                self.bluejay.connect(self.pI) {
                    result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success:
                        self.isConnected = true
                        self.BTButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bluetooth-Logo-on"), for: UIControl.State.normal) //Set BT logo to connected

                    case .failure(let error):
                        debugPrint(error)
                        self.isConnected = false
                        self.BTButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bluetooth-Logo-off"), for: UIControl.State.normal) //Set BT logo to connected
                    }
                }
        })
    }
```

The button will disconnect bluetooth if pressed, but will not turn it back on, for that I have to quit the app and relaunch. Honestly, I do not know why it will disconnect from bluetooth when it is pressed as I dont have any code written to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, and thought I would post if anybody else ran into this problem. I did not have a command to disconnect the bluetooth module, which caused errors for reconnection.

I have since added a branch of logic to determine if the button should be on or off by oscillating a Bool value started by initiating a global variable of BTButton to true.

```
    @IBAction func BTButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {

    if (BTButton) {
        bluejay.disconnect(immediate: true)
        self.BTButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bluetooth-Logo-off"), for: UIControl.State.normal) //Set BT logo to connected
        BTButton = false
    }
    else {
        bluejay.start() //Call Bluejay

        bluejay.scan( //Begin and format BLE scanning
            duration: 10, serviceIdentifiers: [self.serviceID],
            discovery: { [weak self] (discovery, discoveries) -> ScanAction in
                guard let weakSelf = self else {
                    return .stop
                }

                if (discovery.peripheralIdentifier.name == self!.deviceName) {
                    self!.pI = discovery.peripheralIdentifier
                    return .stop
                }

                weakSelf.discoveries = discoveries //Add each discovery to discoveries
                return .continue
            },
            stopped: { (discoveries, error) in

                //Once the correct device is found, connect\\
                self.bluejay.connect(self.pI) {
                    result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success:
                        self.isConnected = true
                        self.BTButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bluetooth-Logo-on"), for: UIControl.State.normal) //Set BT logo to connected

                    case .failure(let error):
                        debugPrint(error)
                        self.isConnected = false
                        self.BTButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bluetooth-Logo-off"), for: UIControl.State.normal) //Set BT logo to connected
                    }
                }
        })
        BTButton = true
    }
}
```